# SwitchPreference (PreferenceAtivity) - Android NULL

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I have a screen preferences, and as such, used the PreferenceActivity, I have everything built and functioning, however a phone (Version 4.1.2) by clicking on the text SwitchPreference (ie anywhere on the row without being in the same switch ) he bursts with a Null Pointer Excetion, but if you click on the same swtich works fine.

What could this be?

error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.Switch.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(Switch.java:550)
    at   android.view.View.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:4621)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View.java:4611)
    at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.sendAccessibilityEvent(TwoStatePreference.java:197)
    at android.preference.SwitchPreference.onBindView(SwitchPreference.java:114)
    at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:463)
    at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:221)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2308)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1330)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1600)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2143)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13850)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1680)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1538)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1451)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13850)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1680)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1669)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1453)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13850)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1680)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1538)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1451)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13850)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13850)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1680)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1538)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1451)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13850)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13850)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1894)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1710)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1013)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4245)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you ever solved it properly? As of today, about 2 years after you have asked that, I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your custom switchPrefrences component

`@Override
    protected void onClick() {
//      Log.e("CustomSwitchPreferences", "onClick called");
    }`

Leave it empty and DO NOT call super.onClick();

This will keep your onPrefrenceChange aside from clicks (switch action won't get affected, just the clicks on the row)